# How to create object in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS  development. Currently I am reading this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/ . I am facing problem when I am reading this line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

I know object in objective-c is created by following way

```
 classname *objecname = [[classname alloc]init];
```

My confusion point is here `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

How `cell` object is created  here? Please tell details.

Comment: As an aside, while the author is illustrating how to update a cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, this is really a bad example. You rarely just update the cell itself. You generally have to update the the model backing the table, too. I know you're new to this, so this might not make sense yet, but I'm just warning you that's it's generally not a good idea to just update a cell like that tutorial demonstrates.

Comment: You know, it's possible to write functions which call `[[class alloc] init]` and return its result. the fact that you don't explicitly *see* an `alloc-init` pair in your code doesn't mean it's impossible for the code to create objects…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have this code in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, is that right?

If so, you're tapping on a cell that is on the screen, so the cell object already exists. Where and how was it created? Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which you have already written.

So when you make this call

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

it just gives you the cell object to work with, but it doesn't create a new one.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the tutorial you linked to, I'm assuming you are dealing with selecting a row. When you select a row, you have access to the `NSIndexPath` of that row, which contains two parts:

1. The section of the cell
2. The row of the cell

With that information, let's break down the confusing code: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

```
UITableViewCell *cell
```

This part declares your variable. You've chosen to name it `cell`. You could just as easily have named it `theCell`, like so:

```
UITableViewCell *theCell
```

The `*` means that you're declaring a pointer, which is just a reference to an actual object, or the table view cell.

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

The `tableView` refers to the `UITableView` that was just selected. `UITableView` has a method called `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and what that method does is retrieve the cell at the specified section and row of the `UITableView`. In your case, it retrieves the row that you've just selected and stores the reference to it in your `cell` variable.

When declaring a **new** object, yes, it would take on the following syntax:

```
classname *objecname = [[classname alloc] init];
```

The key word here is `new`. When dealing with selecting rows in a `UITableView`, you don't want to create a new cell because you can't select a cell that doesn't exist. You want to get the cell that the user has just selected.

Comment: "In iOS, UITableViewCells are reused, so in your code, you're actually retrieving a cell that already exists." Yes, cells are reused, but that's not really relevant here. If we were talking about `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then the cell reuse discussion is interesting, but we're just talking about `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, so this is, as you mention later, merely an example of clicking on an existing cell. Bottom line, cell reuse is good concept for OP to understand, but not relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

The cell is not created with that line. That line gets a reference to a cell that is already in the table view at that indexPath.